# How do I revert to the previous navigation release?

Tags: ros, navigation, package, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running ROS Hydro, and on 3/16/14 I upgraded several packages at Ubuntu's urging. One of those upgraded my navigation to release 1.11.6

Since then, the application I'm developing has worked much worse than it used to. I would really like to revert to the previous release of navigation, but I'm having trouble finding out how.

I have gone to https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/releases and downloaded the zip file from the previous release into my Hydro_workspace folder, but I can't figure out how to properly build it.

I've also tried Synaptic Package Manager. It shows the package but the option to force the previous version is grayed out.

Using `apt-cache showpkg ros-hydro-navigation`, it looks like only the most recent release is available.

Is there any good way to get the previous version to install in my /opt/ros/hydro folder like it was before? I am still fighting with getting the zip I downloaded to do anything useful, and I will be the first to admit that makefiles, etc, are very much not my forte.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141981/how-do-i-revert-to-the-previous-navigation-release?/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have a Hydro workspace located in `~/hydrows`, all you should have to do is compile the release you want in the workspace, and then the ROS should automatically use that version instead of the version in `/opt/ros/hydro/`.

```
cd ~/hydrows/src
wget https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/archive/1.11.5.tar.gz
tar xvf 1.11.5.tar.gz
cd ~/hydrows
catkin_make
rm ~/hydrows/src/1.11.5.tar.gz
```

If the compilation succeeds you can test that ROS finds this version by typing `roscd navigation` and you should be taken to `~/hydrows/src/navigation-1.11.5/navigation`.  If compilation fails, you could try `rosdep update` and `rosdep install navigation` to ensure you have the proper dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-03-19**:
Wow, that was detailed, thanks! I will have to try it. So "hydrows" is a catkin style workspace?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-03-20**:
yes exactly... you mentioned you were using hydro, so I just assumed you already had a catkin workspace setup, although it may be in a different location.

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-03-20**:
Thanks; my issue is project is in a rosbuild-style workspace, and it includes a navfn object. So when I source the setup.bash of the rosbuild workspace to compile my project, how do I get it to include the navfn object as defined in the new catkin workspace? Or does my project need to be in catkin?